# CSS selector id not working

Tags: html, css

here is my code: http://jsbin.com/sinacel/edit?html,css,output

`#octagon` selector doesn't work at all, and doesn't get any styling.

it should produce at least a red background, but this is what I get instead [image]

I'm using Google Chrome latest version. 
Any idea why this could happen or is it happening just on my pc?

Comment: Go through the code a couple of time before posting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put a wrong id `<button id="#octagon">` instead of `<button id="octagon">`

Comment: ohh im so dumb, what a rookie miss. definitely shouldn't stay much longer on pc. thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the html where you have `id=“#octagon”` it should be `id=“octagon”` no hash

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `css` to style your website just remember it 
while you use `id` so in css you tell it with `#` but e.g

```
<button id="try">
 </button>
```

so in css you can call that style with

```
#try{
background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It should like this

```
<button id="octagon">BUY NOW </button>
```

Remove the `#`, `#`is selector for id in BOM.

Comment: How does your answer add anything that hasn't been said already by the other answers and comments?