# can't edit button style with css

Tags: html, css

my css don't work:

```css
.arthur{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.easy {
  background-color: #4CAF50; 
}

.medium {
  background-color: #FFC107; 
}

.myButton {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #44c767 5%, #5cbf2a 100%);
  background-color:#44c767;
  border-radius:28px;
  border:1px solid #18ab29;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:17px;
  padding:16px 31px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Jeux d'arcade</title>
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bouton.css">
  <body>
    <img src="arcade.jpg" id="arthur">
    <h1>Jeux d'arcade</h1>
    <p>Sélectionnez le niveau de difficulté :</p>
    <a href="#" id="myButton">Facile</a>
    <button id="medium">Normal</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

try re-link css to html,
try change the ids,
and thought about replacing button with `<a>`
the css is properly linked to my html however,
it appears that I can't add style to the button,
`<a>` don't change whatever I do

Comment: Replace the dot with an # for style

Comment: I changed class names in the snippet to make it works fine. As the given text ask to replace it, maybe it's not a typo. Hope I didn't something wrong

Comment: @Elikill58 you've changed the question by removing the very issue they were asking about.

Comment: @DanielBeck if the issue is only the #, the question is a typo

Comment: I've rolled back your edit.  Please don't "correct" errors in a question, they're very likely the reason for the question in the first place.

Comment: Rolled back the preceding edit as well, because they did the same thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between an id and a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/whats-the-difference-between-an-id-and-a-class)

Comment: @DanielBeck Sad for the snippet. But this question is duplicate also of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12889362/10952503), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47256387/10952503), or some others and it's also a typo ...

Comment: It's not a typo, it's a consistent mistake the user is making.  Agreed on the duplicate you pointed out, though.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your CSS selector *myButton* is only targeting elements which have the **class** *myButton* assigned. Currently your a-tag only has the **id** of *myButton* assigned.

To get it running, adapt your a-tag e.g. by exchanging *id* for *class* like so:

```
<a href="#" class="myButton">Facile</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You got the selectors `.` and `#` mixed up. In your CSS part change `.myButton` to `#myButton` and `.medium` to `#medium` **OR** in your HTML part `<a href="#" id="myButton">Facile</a>` to `<a href="#" class="myButton">Facile</a>` and `<button id="medium">Normal</button>` to `<button class="medium">Normal</button>`. You can read more about selectors here https://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/